# Mapbox: What color-code does queryRenderedFeatures return? How to convert the values to rgba, hex or hsl?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

The example on mapbox.com returns nice information on the hovered feature, also the fill-color https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/

The fill-color returned looks like this:

```
   "feature": {
       "type": "Feature",
       "layer": {
           "id": "data",
           "type": "fill",
           "source": "jsx-source-1",
           "paint": {
               "fill-color": {
                   "r": 0.6398494117647059,
                   "g": 0.26332078431372546,
                   "b": 0.1670227450980392,
                   "a": 0.7
               }
           },
           "layout": {}
       },
       "source": "jsx-source-1",
       "state": {}
   },
```

The label "r", "g", "b", "a" seems to be rbga color code, but the returned values are not. What is this?

Any idea how to convert this into rgba, hex, hsl?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Multiply the single values by 255 in order to get an rgb code, leave the "a" (alpha) as it is.